# How to use math in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating database view but How can I calculate ant put that column like picture.

[image]

EDIT:

```
SELECT 
   orders.id AS order_id, 
   order_products.qty AS p_count, 
   order_products.unit_price AS p_price, 
   order_products.pp_calculated, 
   orders.customer_id, 
   products.point_percentage AS point_percentage 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN order_products ON orders.id = order_products.order_id 
INNER JOIN products ON order_products.product_id = products.id
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `SELECT (the red bit) as pp_calculated` --- See with pictures I cannot copy and paste from the question into an answer. So as I am lazy I may not even bother trying to answer the question

Comment: SELECT
 orders.id AS order_id,
 order_products.qty AS p_count,
 order_products.unit_price AS p_price,
 order_products.pp_calculated,
 orders.customer_id,
 products.point_percentage AS point_percentage 
FROM
 orders
 INNER JOIN order_products ON orders.id = order_products.order_id
 INNER JOIN products ON order_products.product_id = products.id

Comment: @VepaMirzayev: It is much better to [edit] your question, and add info, like long SQL statements....   Or, if you are trying to answer you own question, post it as answer, and mark the question as solved.  (I just did do the EDIT for you)

Answer (score 0):

you can refer alias in same query. Try this

```
SELECT 
   orders.id AS order_id, 
   order_products.qty AS p_count, 
   order_products.unit_price AS p_price, 
  ((order_products.qty*order_products.unit_price*100)/products.point_percentage)pp_calculated
   orders.customer_id, 
   products.point_percentage AS point_percentage 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN order_products ON orders.id = order_products.order_id 
INNER JOIN products ON order_products.product_id = products.id
```